# Admixture Enties Python tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

When i try to type any text in one entry from the add window it goes to all Entries

The project idea is encrypting and saving passwords, when you click add in the main window

another window that haves three entries will pop up, and when you try to type any thing in one

of those its like you typing it in all entries in the same times so that is the problem .

and that is the source code:

```
# Import Modules
from tkinter import *
from webbrowser import open_new
# Make Sure The File Is Running Directly
if __name__=="__main__" :
    pass
else :
    quit()
#
# Create And Setting Up The Main Window

app = Tk()
app.title('Password Manager')
app.geometry('370x300')
app.config(bg='#bbf5fa')
app.resizable(False,False)
app.iconbitmap("")

# Add Password To Database (Encrypted Text file )
def add():
    # Setting Up The Add Window
    add=Toplevel()
    add.geometry("500x250")
    add.resizable(False,False)
    add.title("Add Password")
    add.config(bg="#59f05e")
    Site_name=   Entry(add,bd=2,bg="#ba9270",fg="black",text=("Oswald",15,'bold'))
    Site_name.place(x=175,y=50,width=300,height=30)
    Username= Entry(add,bd=2,bg="#ba9270",fg="black",text=("Oswald",15,'bold'))
    Username.place(x=175,y=90,width=300,height=30)
    Password = Entry(add,bd=2,bg="red",fg="black",show="*",text=("Oswald",15,'bold'))
    
    Password.place(x=175,y=130,width=300,height=30)
    lb1=Label(add,fg="#e30ece",font=('Playfair Display',13,"bold"),text="Site Name : ",bg='#59f05e')
    lb2=Label(add,fg="#e30ece",font=('Playfair Display',13,"bold"),text="User Name : ",bg='#59f05e')
    lb3=Label(add,fg="#e30ece",font=('Playfair Display',13,"bold"),text="Password : ",bg='#59f05e')
    bt=Button(add,text="Submit",bg="cyan",fg="red",font=("Oswald",10,"bold"))
    bt.place(x=175,y=185,width=200,height=50)
    lb1.place(x=65,y=50)
    lb2.place(x=65,y=90)
    lb3.place(x=65,y=130)
    
    
    # Encrypting And Regestring Passwords
    



# Decrypt And View Data
def view():
    # Setting Up The View Window
    view=Toplevel()
    view.title("View Passwords")
    view.geometry("400x300")
    view.resizable(False,False)
    # Decrypting Password

def mychannel():
    open_new("https://www.youtube.com/@cheikh11")
text = Label(app,fg="blue",font=('Sedgwick Ave Display',13,"bold"),text="Password Manager",bg='#bbf5fa')
text.place(x=115,y=10)
btn1=Button(app,text="Add New ",bg="green",fg="black",font=("Oswald",15,"bold"),command=add)
btn1.place(x=115,y=50,width=150,height=50)
btn2= Button(app,text="View",bg="orange",fg="black",font=("Oswald",15,"bold"),command=view)
btn2.place(x=115,y=115,width=150,height=50)
btn3= Button(app,text="Visite My Channel",bg="cyan",fg="black",font=("Oswald",10,"bold"),command=mychannel)
btn3.place(x=115,y=175,width=150,height=50)
btn4= Button(app,text="Exit",bg="red",fg="black",font=("Oswald",15,"bold"),command=app.destroy)
btn4.place(x=115,y=235,width=150,height=50)
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: I think `text=("Oswald",15,'bold')` should be `font=("Oswald",15,"bold")` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by replacing the attribute text in the entry with font because
there is no attribute named text in entry but it doesn't gives you an error

**before : **

```
Site_name=   Entry(add,bd=2,bg="#ba9270",fg="black",text=("Oswald",13,'bold'))
Site_name.place(x=175,y=50,width=300,height=30)
```

**after : **

```
Site_name=   Entry(add,bd=2,bg="#ba9270",fg="black",font=("Oswald",13,'bold'))
Site_name.place(x=175,y=50,width=300,height=30)
```

Comment: `text` will be treated as `textvariable` option.